# JAXB: using @XmlID along with Hibernate @Id

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2, jaxb2-basics

I have following hibernate property:

```
@Id()   
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id = null;
```

I want to add JAXB annotation @XmlID to this id but @XmlID can only be applied to String data types. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IDAdapter.class) along with @XmlID where IDAdapter is

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class IDAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Long> {

    @Override
    public Long unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseLong(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Long value) throws Exception {
        return DatatypeConverter.printLong(value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlID
@Transient
public String getXId(){
    return this.id;
}
public String setXId(String s){
    this.id = Long.parseDouble(s);
}
```